# Hosting files via XAMPP

Tags: xampp, hosting

So I want to host music for my game via XAMPP, I have written the code in AS3 in the client already for it to grab the link and get the mp3 files, but I never really hosted anything off of XAMPP before except for my games database, what folder would I put the sfx folder with all the mp3 files to where I can make the link; ip:port/sfx/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the XAMPP folder, there is a folder called 'htdocs'. If you create a subfolder in this folder, it will be accessible.

I.e., put the folder 'sfx' directly in the htdocs folder.

Comment: Thanks, all works good now. Will mark as answer in 6 minutes when it lets me.